# Apigee route post to get api

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, microservices, apigee

I have a GET API exposed as (`www.example.com/find/cola?id=lite,fiz`)

From Apigee I want to expose a POST API instead of GET like (`www.example.com/api/find`)

Body `{id:['cola','fiz']}`

Is it possible to accept post api and transform and route as get from apigee proxy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make your Apigee-based proxy accept a POST query, and convert it so that on the south-bound leg your back-end receives the converted GET call. You should be able to use an Assign Message Policy in your proxy to do that:
https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/reference/policies/assign-message-policy#set-verb